# ICEfaces and NetBeans error

Tags: java, netbeans, icefaces

I create a new web project from netbeans and I chose ICEFACES for frameworks
Below I chose create welcomeICEFACES.jspx and welcomICEFACES.html, So when I run it Ok.
But when I want to start with a new page, for example Index.jsp, I edit web.xml but when run it start with http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/welcomeICEfaces.iface, I don't know where to edit, can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when you add index.jsp to the project, still when you launch the project, it starts with WelcomeICEfaces.iface?

In this case you have to change the welcome-file-list tag as follows:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```